# ElasticSearch: Filtering on aggrigation top_hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of articles where one article is a combination of several posts. One post is one document in ES.
Every post has a postId, articleId, timestamp, and a status (simplified version). 
The article's status is the status of the last post within the same article that were logged. 
I want to query for articles with a specific status and only return the articleId as the result. This means that I have to group on articleId, order by timestamp and finally filter the result by status.

I have managed to do the grouping and the ordering, but I'm kinda stuck on the last part.

Our data looks kinda like this:

```
postid  articleId   timestamp               status

1       1           01.01.2016 00:00:01     Success
2       1           01.01.2016 00:00:03     Success
3       1           01.01.2016 00:00:02     Error

4       2           01.01.2016 00:00:01     Success
5       2           01.01.2016 00:00:03     Error
6       2           01.01.2016 00:00:02     Success
```

With my current query i get this:

```
articeid    latestStatus

1           Success
2           Error
```

I want to write a query where I ask for the articleId for (for example) all articles with status Error.
This query should return:

```
articeid

2
```

This is what I got so far:

```
GET /_search
{    
    "size": 0,     
    "aggs": {
        "message_status": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "articleId"
            },            
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "processed": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using both post_filter and and bucket_selector with scripting, but can't get it to work.

The query above returns this:

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "message_status": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "1337",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_docs": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 3,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "article",
                           "_type": "post",
                           "_id": "3",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "postId": 3,
                              "articleId": "1337",
                              "processed": "2016-10-10T12:47:25.570852+02:00",
                              "statusId": 6
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              1476096445570
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "42",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_docs": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 3,
                     "max_score": null,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "article",
                           "_type": "post",
                           "_id": "6",
                           "_score": null,
                           "_source": {
                              "postId": 6,
                              "articleId": "42",
                              "processed": "2016-10-10T13:02:59.399726+02:00",
                              "statusId": 5
                           },
                           "sort": [
                              1476097379399
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve now is to filter this response on a specific statusId and only return the articleIds.

I greatly appreciate all help!

**Update:**

Here is my mapping

```
{
   "article": {
      "mappings": {
         "post": {
            "properties": {               
               "articleId": {
                  "type": "string"
               },              
               "postId": {
                  "type": "integer"
               },
               "processed": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
               },
               "statusId": {
                  "type": "integer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: PLease share the mapping of your index

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

PLease try following query:

```
GET article/_search
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
  "term": {
     "status": {
        "value": "error"
     }
   }
 },
 "aggs": {
  "group By articls": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "articleId"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "top hits": {
           "top_hits": {
              "size": 1,
              "_source" :["articleId"],
              "sort": [
                 {
                    "timestamp": {
                       "order": "desc"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Result would be something like:

```
 "buckets": [
        {
           "key": 2,
           "doc_count": 1,
           "top hits": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 1,
                 "max_score": null,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "article",
                       "_type": "article",
                       "_id": "3",
                       "_score": null,
                       "_source": {
                          "articleId": 2
                       },
                       "sort": [
                          1444435200000
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     ]
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Richa. Thank you for your answer!
We have already tried a variant of your solution. This does the filtering before the grouping as far as we can tell and as such gives us false positives, since we're interested in the status with the latest timestamp

Comment: your solutions is a bit tricky as the elasticsearch don't have a document selector from the grouped/aggregated data, but think you can take some leverage/workaround from script aggregations. take a look at them https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html .Try to play with map, reduce, combine script after grouping the data on articleid

Comment: yeah i did a deep look at the script metric aggregations, i think you can achieve what you are looking for after playing around with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) will give you the desired results. This the query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "user_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "articleId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "error_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "statusId": 0
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_processed_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "processed"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "success_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "statusId": 1
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_processed_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "processed"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "only_error_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "error_timestamp": "error_filter.latest_processed_timestamp",
              "success_timestamp": "success_filter.latest_processed_timestamp"
            },
            "script": "error_timestamp > success_timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Initially, I aggregate over *articleId*, then there are two filters. *success filter* filters the document with statusId : 1(I have assumed success means 1 and Error means 0 from your mapping) whereas *error filter* filters the document with statusId : 0

After that I am finding latest processed timestamp for each filter and finally in bucket selector we only retain buckets where error timestamp was greater than success timestamp. This will give you one bucket with articleId 2.